# Is CALayer insertSublayer: atindex: destructive?

Tags: iphone, calayer

The documentation is not clear on what happens the the layer currently atindex:xy when using insertSublayer:abc.layer atindex:xy.
My experimentation has had mixed results.
My understanding is index 0 is furthest from the user (all other layers would be above that one).

If I call insertSublayer:abc.layer atindex:0, and def.layer is already at index:0, does def.layer get destroyed, or shifted to index:1?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is not destructive. `insertSublayer:atIndex:` just inserts that sublayer at that index in the sublayers array, and has all the normal behavior associated with array insertion in an NSMutableArray

Answer (score 0):

`def.layer` gets shifted to index:1, `insertSublayer` does simple insertion, NOT replacement.