# replace CALayer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, user-interface, calayer, gradient

I am following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/422066/gradients-on-uiview-and-uilabels-on-iphone/1931498#1931498) to create a gradient using a `CALayer`. The
key command is

```
[view.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
```

My problem is that I would like to update the gradient regularly. If I call the above code repeatedly, then nothing happens as new gradients are placed under the old ones. See
[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759460/is-calayer-insertsublayer-atindex-destructive).

My question is: how does one replace a sublayer with another one. I should probably call
`replaceSublayer:with:`. But to do this, I need a reference to the old gradient. Is there a dynamic way of obtaining this. Something like `[view.layer getSublayerAtIndex: 0]`? Is the easiest way to just store a reference to the current gradient in the viewcontroller?

Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    [[view layer] replaceSublayer:[[[view layer] sublayers] objectAtIndex:0] with:gradient];
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get a sublayer, you should use this method:

```
[view.layer.sublayers objectAtIndex:0];
```

Then you can replace the sublayer via

```
[view.layer replaceSublayer:[view.layer.sublayers objectAtIndex:0] with:yourNewGradient];
```

Comment: No problem! :) PS: The same method is used with subviews (but you use `subviews` array instead.

Answer (score 1):

Besides replacing the layer, you can just update the existing CAGradientLayer's `colors`, `locations`, and other properties to change the parameters of the displayed gradient.